# Phpmyadmin - stored routine is meant to return multiply rows in the javascript function but instead returns a single row

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i have a stored routine called collection_get_category_suggestions which has the following sql

```
select *
from album 
where category=InCategory;
```

This should return a list of multiple records based on a category the user chooses. When run in sql tab the result of the routine returns multiple values however when executed in the routine tab and JavaScript it will only return the first record. Here is my JavaScript function which handles sql.

```
function getCategorySuggestions(catid)
{
var categoryid = catid;
    console.log(categoryid);
    selectedcategory = categoryid;
    $("#suggestionsTab").empty();

    var url = "categories_xml.php?category=" + selectedcategory;
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){     
            var album_title = $(xml).find('album_title').text();
            console.log(album_title);
            var artist = $(xml).find('artist').text();
            var year = $(xml).find('year').text();
            var imageurl = $(xml).find('imageurl').text();
            var categoryinfo = "<h3>" + album_title + "</h3><p>" + artist + " (" + year + ")</p>";
            //categoryinfo += "<img src='" + imageurl + "' alt='" + album_title + " Album Cover' height='200' width='200' />";  
            console.log(categoryinfo);          
            $('#suggestionsTab').append(categoryinfo);  
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }
        });
}
```

the console.log returns one record. Why is this? Thanks very much for any help

EDIT:

php script

```
<?php
            // Include utility files
            require_once 'include/config.php';  

            // Load the database handler
            require_once BUSINESS_DIR . 'database_handler.php'; 

            // Load Business Tier
            require_once BUSINESS_DIR . 'collection.php';

            header("Content-type: text/xml");
            $response='<?xml version = "1.0" ?><albums>';   
            if (isset($_GET['category']))
            {
                $obj = Collection::GetCategorySuggestions($_GET['category']);
                $album_title=$obj['album_title'];
                $artist=$obj['artist'];
                $category=$obj['category'];
                $year=$obj['release_date'];
                $imageurl="./images/" . $obj['image'];
                $response .= '<album><album_title>' . htmlentities($album_title, ENT_QUOTES) . '</album_title>';
                $response .= '<artist>' . htmlentities($artist, ENT_QUOTES) . '</artist>';
                $response .= '<category>' . htmlentities($category, ENT_QUOTES) . '</category>';
                $response .= '<year>' . $year . '</year>';              
                $response .= '<imageurl>' . htmlentities($imageurl, ENT_QUOTES) . '</imageurl></album>';                
            }
            $response .= '</albums>';
            echo $response;
?>
```

i should add that the collection.php function is

```
public static function GetCategorySuggestions($category)
    {
        // Build SQL query
        $sql = 'CALL collection_get_category_suggestions (:category)';

        // Build the parameters array
        $params = array (':category' => $category);

        // Execute the query and return the results
        return DatabaseHandler::GetRow($sql, $params);
    }
```

foreach loop

```
foreach($albumsarray as $album)             
            {
                $album_id=$album['album_id'];
                $album_title=$album['album_title'];
                $artist=$album['artist'];               

                $response .= '<album><album_id>' . $album_id . '</album_id><album_title>' . htmlentities($album_title, ENT_QUOTES) . '</album_title><artist>' . htmlentities($artist, ENT_QUOTES) . '</artist></album>';
            }
```

Comment: The Javascript isn't handling SQL at all. There's a PHP script that is handling the SQL. If the response to your AJAX call is only returning one row, look at the PHP code for the reason.

Comment: Can you show your php code? Are you fetching all data from mysql? Edit: i am not sure but does your xml nodes has mismatch?

Comment: absolutely i did realise the php script was handling this... my fault for not adding it to the answer - There edited

Comment: Can you declare `Collection::GetCategorySuggestions` we are not using your framework.

Comment: HddnTHA is that a reference to the collection.php? i have added this now

Comment: I cant see any loop. I am not sure you are fetching all datas from sql.

Comment: similar to this - see edit

Comment: Yes you need a loop in php like foreach or while to fetch all data.

Comment: how would this change the javascript?

Comment: im a little unsure how i would edit the php file to test this?

Comment: I am not familiar of javacript but, your xml nodes must be pass to the javascript.

Comment: okay thank yes i think i have got it

Comment: Well, i am on mobile i cant edit it atm. May be someone who is computergeek come to help you for your code.

Comment: May be @Dagon can help

Comment: i would appreciate the help to be honest... im not great at php scripts. Also good to have an answer for others

Comment: If @Fred-ii- is online i bett he would like to help you with your code

Comment: Yes of course that is why i linked their names.